# Why isn't normal light used to cut stuff?

Tags: visible-light, laser

Like many people, I have tried burning stuff with magnifying glass. Where I live, the power of sun is some 600 watts per square meter at most. If my magnifying glass is 10cm in diameter I have only 4,7 watts on my focus point. It can light paper instantly.

This makes me wonder why do we have laser cutters. A few hundred watts of ordinary light could do the same. It would seem much easier to have just ordinary light source. No expensive CO2 or fiber lasers. Just a simple high power led for example.

I guess that the reason is that laser light is coherent. Another thing that comes to my mind is that sunligt is practically collimated as the sun is so far. Maybe achieving same with artificial light is not so easy.

What is the real reason?

Comment: What kind of source do you propose to use instead?

Comment: This appears to be more of an engineering question than physics.

Comment: @KyleKanos Possibly, but a complete answer does involve discussing some fairly fundamental optics, such as the limits arising from aberration and étendue.

Comment: Rod Vance's answer is accurate but it does not highlight ultimate issue: **you cannot collate sunlight — or even normal light — down to a "dot"**. Laser concentrates its energy into an extremely narrow beam, meaning that the area it impacts is very small. You cannot do that with white light from a source like the Sun, or from lamps.

Comment: tldr;  Concentrating *and* [collimating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collimated_light) broadband light into a narrow and long beam is hard to impossible.

Comment: The problem is not that the Sun is "broadband" or, that it's "white".  The problem is, the Sun is _big_.  If you could shrink the Sun down to the size of a pea, without changing its spectrum or diminishing its total energy output, then you could use geometric optics to concentrate its light into laser-like beams, or focus it onto spots with laser-like energy density.

Comment: @jameslarge Absolutely. Incoherent is not the same as high aberration or high étendue. You could have broadband light with low wavefront aberration - it would be easy to focus this into a spot.

Comment: @J... No, incoherent is not the same as high aberration or high étendue. You could have broadband light with low wavefront aberration - it would be easy to focus this into a spot.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance A spot != collimated.  Spots are fine if you're cutting objects with zero thickness.  Usually that's not the case.

Comment: @J... Yes but a spot can also be superposition of arbitrarily many wavelengths. You can focus broadband light - it is a question of wavefront aberration and étendue, not coherence.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance I'm not sure we're disagreeing here...

Comment: @J... And a diffraction limited spot is, abstractly, the same thing as collimated. They are Fourier transforms of one another, and readily converted into one another with passive, low aberration lenses.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance yes... which is hard (ie: expensive).  Harder than for a single wavelength, and increasingly so as the beam waist gets small.  You can't have abberation with a single wavelength.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This has nothing to do with coherence or the fundamental physics distinction between "normal" and laser light.

It's simply a question of finding a source that is intense enough to induce a fine cutting edge. That is, the source must be both powerful *and* one must be able to concentrate it into a very small spot. Cutting happens when there is highly intense local heating in a very small area of the sample.

The mechanism of stimulated emission allows the generation of huge amounts of light all in exactly the same momentum state. What this means is that the output is high power and very nearly a plane wave, with a low aberration wavefront. Such a wave can be focussed to near to a diffraction limited spot. Thus stimulated emission enables both the fundamental requirements of power and low wavefront aberration, equating in this case to high ability for concentration.

At $10{\rm \mu m}$ wavelength, that of a ${\rm CO}_2$ industrial machining laser, that implies a spot size of about $20{\rm \mu m}$ focused through a $0.3NA$ optical system. With thousands of watts continuously output, this equates to an intensity of terawatts per square meter at the "cutting edge".

In contrast, the Sun is *not* a collimated source - it is an extended one. The best you can do is focus it down to a tiny image of the Sun. Let's do our calculation for a 0.3NA lens one meter across. The distance to the sample is then about 3 meters. The image of the Sun is then $\frac{3}{1.5\times10^{11}} \times 5\times 10^8$ meters across, or about one centimeter across. Through our one meter lens, we get about $600{\rm W}$. So we get about the same power as in our laser example (somewhat less) through an area that is $\left(\frac{0.01}{2\times 10^{-5}}\right)^2 =2.5\times 10^5$ times as large. Our intensity is thus five or six orders of magnitude less than in the laser example.

There is limited ability to improve this situation with a bigger lens; as the lens gets wider, you need to set it back further from the target, with the result that the area of the Sun image grows at the same rate as the area of the lens, and thus the input power. The intensity stays roughly the same.

**LEDs**

The OP also asks about LEDs. Although modern LEDs can output amazing powers, they, like the Sun, are also an extended source, comprising a significant area of highly divergent point sources, so the light output has a high étendue and cannot be concentrated into a tight spot. This highest power  LEDs needfully have a large area semiconductor chip whence the emission comes. In a laser cavity, it is also true that the first seem emissions are also highly divergent, and the first pass through the gain medium produces an amplified spherical wavefront. However, the design of the resonant cavity means that only a small, on-axis section of that spherical wave bounces back into the cavity, most of it is lost. On the second pass, we have an amplified, lower curvature wavefront; most of this is lost at the other end of the cavity too. During the first few passes, therefore, the process is quite inefficient, but on each bounce the wavefront gets flatter and flatter as only light components directed accurately along the cavity axis can stay in the cavity and the efficiency of recirculation swiftly increase. Through this mechanism of resonance, therefore, the stimulated emission process is restricted to only the most on-axis components of the light. Thus, the combined mechanisms of resonance and stimulated emission co-ordinate the whole wave so that ultimately it is a plane wave, propagating back and forth in a cavity, spread over a relatively wide cross section so that heat loading from any losses are not damaging to the cavity. This near-zero [étendue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue), low aberration field is easily focused to a diffraction limited spot.

**Solar Furnace**

User Martin Beckett gives the example of the Odeillo solar furnace:

> You can however use lots of lenses (or mirrors)

This is in keeping with my solar lens example above. A solar furnace is great for furnace applications, such as mass energy production or smelting. But the focused light lacks the intensity needed for cutting. The intensity in this example is about the same as for our one meter mirror. The furnace focuses several megawatts through a 40cm diameter focus, and a a few megawatts through a 40cm focus is about the same intensity as one kilowatt through a 1cm wide focus, which is what we had for our solar lens example.

Comment: You can however use lots of lenses (or mirrors) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odeillo_solar_furnace

Comment: @MartinBeckett Great for a furnace, not so good for fine cutting, though. Moreover, the intensity is about the same as for our one meter mirror (a few megawatts through a 40cm focus is about the same intensity as a kilowatt through a 1cm wide focus).

Comment: But if a giant ant was to terrorize southern France and we could lure it into the right spot it could be very useful

Comment: @MartinBeckett LOL! That sounds like a Goodies or a Red Dwarf scenario

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance What about [Solar-pumped lasers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar-pumped_laser) though? From what I understand, these only use sunlight indirectly, but can be used for cutting. Not strictly what OP asked but maybe you can offer some additional context on them?

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Out of curiosity, does the exact wavelength of the light affect whether or not the cutting device is effective? I'd imagine certain wavelengths would be more effective at cutting certain materials, but I don't have any concrete science to back that up.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance - good answer, the time I have wasted trying to convince to people that AΩ  is conserved

Comment: The diode lasers used for cutting are essentially LEDs. They slap 10-20 diodes together. Combining is basically butting up each diode's output to a single large multimodal fiber. The bandwidth is something like 10-20 nm at 900 nm, so it's essentially incoherent light.

Comment: @user71659 Incoherent, but not high wavefront aberration. They are two different things. You could have arbitrarily broadband light with low wavefront aberration - it would be easy to focus this into a spot.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance This is why I mentioned how they combine into a multimodal fiber. They hit a ton of different modes so the wavefront is a mess. The factor is called M^2 in a laser, where M^2=1 in a Gaussian beam, multidiode lasers can have M^2 easily of 10-20, which means the minimum spot is larger than a Gaussian by that factor.

Comment: @user71659 An $M^2$ of 20 is still a long way from  sunlight or a lightbuld - it still focusses better.

Comment: In first sentence you wrote it has nothing to do with coherence, and after you proceed to explain coherent mechanism of stimulated emission making possible diffraction limited focusing. Well, it has everything to do with coherence.

Comment: @KabaT The association is coincidental. Low aberration and low étendue are completely independent from coherence. One can have low aberration and low étendue sources that are very incoherent, and these can be focussed perfectly. Take for example sunlight that one focusses onto an Airy disk sized pinhole and then recollimates the output. The output is incoherent, zero étendue, aberration free light, which can be focussed to a point easily. THe catch is that you lose most of your original sunlight, so it will not be high intensity. It's simply that lasers are a source of low aberration ....

Comment: @KabaT ... low étendue light, which is what you need. There are broadband lasers that output light intense enough for cutting - bandwidths of tens of nanometers. The usual $CO_2$ laser configuration used in industrial cutting applications has extremely poor coherence - it's not a factor that is of the slightest consequence in that application.

Comment: Yeah, so if you do what you wrote with sunlight, in this way you will make light with high spatial coherence. It will still be not very coherent in time though but that is not important for focusing. Broadband lasers (which I am building btw) have broad spectra but can have very high degree of spatial coherence - like fiber sources.

Answer (score 5):

In theory, sunlight can be used to cut things. In the paper [*Concentration of sunlight to solar-surface levels using non-imaging optics*](https://www.nature.com/articles/339198a0), Gleckman *et al* demonstrate the ability to concentrate the radiant flux of sunlight by 56,000 times, getting to within one order of magnitude of D. Rodriguez's answer for laser light flux above.

However, conservation of [etendue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue) means that the maximum amplification is inversely correlated with the acceptance angle, meaning that the sun tracking required to keep the concentrated point at the highest temperature would need to be extremely precise, and probably several times more expensive than a CO₂ laser, solar generator, and battery. Add to this the fact that the solar concentrator setup can't "store" sunlight when it's not in use (which means that every minute that it has suitable sunlight and isn't in use is a minute wasted) and it becomes even more uneconomical.

Comment: Interesting. This is still five orders of magnitude lower than the laser example I did, although if this scheme achieves 56000 times concentration in practice, it would still be formidable as it would be pretty much as far as one could go within the bounds of thermodynamics. So in theory they'd give you a $5000K$ or $6000K$ heat source, which could drive a heat engine with over $90%$ efficiency conversion. Finding the materials for such an engine might be a problem, though.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance typically molten NaCl. It's a reasonably efficient way of storing solar power. The 3000K salt is used to make steam to drive a turbine after the sun goes down.

Comment: @MartinBeckett I was referring more to the heat engine materials. I'm a long way from my field but I understand that a big limit to efficiency with thermal power plants is that we can't make engines to brook higher than about 900C intake temperature; economical materials such as the steels used for turbines begin to yield at that temperature. I did see briefly about 10 years ago in the popular science press proposals to make small steam turbines out of exotic ceramics that would run at thousands of degrees  with solar concentrators but I think this was more for "personal" use and I guess....

Comment: ... that was overtaken by the low cost of photovoltaics - it just becomes cheaper to cover the roof of a small house.

Answer (score 1):

I only looked at the other answers quickly, but I haven't seen anyone mention the role of material properties.

IIRC, many materials absorb very well at 10.2 um. If they didn't, it wouldn't matter how much power you put on it because it'd all be reflected (a potential safety or equipment damage hazard).

Since you have good absorption and readily available high power sources, you can create very hot localized spots on a material as the others mentioned. These steep temperature gradients enable you to make clean cuts.

Answer (score -3):

Because the energy contained in sunlight is not high enough to increase the rate of vibration of the atoms of an object to the point where the bonds break. The melting and boiling points of the compounds constituting an object are what determine the nature of light that can be used. Lenses can be used to reduce the wavelength of light hence increase it's vibration but with sunlight, numerous changes have to be done such as using a solar panel and then later transforming the resultant electric energy to laser or to power a cutting tool (in essence sunlight is being used)

Comment: This is way, *way* wrong. Sunlight [can](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentrated_solar_power) be used to melt solids, and lenses *cannot* change the wavelength of light.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I thought focusing light was about lowering its wavelength. I guess its about diverting the direction onto a single point. I thought the combination of two waves results in a new characteristic I.e wavelength or amplitude. Which solid can be cut by sunlight?